# Cold Booting a Server over IP KVM - Which Type of PDU is Required?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse, power-distribution-unit

If I get an IP KVM, what type of Power Distribution Unit (PDU) would I need in order to perform cold boots of a server? Would I need a switched type of PDU or will any PDU be okay?

I am looking for a cheap solution so that I can reboot a single server at a remote location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options to cold boot a server remotely:

1. A IP, managed(Switched) PDU that can turn the power outlets on / off
2. A Remote Management Card in the server(DRAC, Lights Out, etc)
3. A local set of hands

The remote management card will provide both your power control, and remote KVM functionality.  If you have equipment that does not offer remote management, a switched/managed PDU is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got an external IPKVM, you'll need some sort of remotely-accessable power switch.  They're not spectacularly expensive, but the better class of colo will usually offer a remotely-accessable power rail as part of the service.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [UPS](http://www.tripplite.com/en/products/model.cfm?txtSeriesID=650&EID=13863&txtModelID=2853), it's a small one with one of the plugs on it is a switchable load one.
Which means you can remotely power cycle it.  They have other models of UPS with more if you needed that.

I've never found a PDU for a small setup cheaper.  I've used one of this series for years, no issues

Comment: So you can remotely turn off + on the power to an individual server?

Have you configured the BIOS of your server to power up the server once power is restored or do you use a Magic Key command and Remote on LAN (via the network interface card) to power it up?

Comment: Correct, the one I have, has 3 switchable plugs.  The UPS plugs into the network and gets an IP address and I setup aport forward for it from the router so I can access from outside the network.  Then if any one of the servers crashed I logged into the UPS from the web and switched off that plug and then back on.  
The BIOS on the server was set to always on so it would power back up.  & hope it booted properly at that point but atleast I was able to power cycle it.

Comment: You can seriously piss off a datacentre by putting an UPS inside your own rack.

Comment: @SpaceManSpiff The link is dead. Can you add the model number of the UPS you mean?

Comment: @AndreKR looks like it's the SMART500RT1U (the "txtModelID" field is the same here: https://datasheet.octopart.com/SMART500RT1U-Tripp-Lite-datasheet-8548654.pdf)

Comment: @TomO'Connor's comment has been further addressed in [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/928159/172060).